# d3.js: Bar chart overflows labels

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, bar-chart

I've got a d3 bar chart with a height of 270 pixels.  The chart renders fine, but it overruns the x-axis labels.

When I attempt to adjust either the `y` or `height` attributes of the bars, they overrun the bounds of the `svg`, either at the topmost (adjust `height`), or bottom-most (adjust `y`).  How can I give the bars a bottom "margin," which will accommodate the labels?

Function which builds the chart:

```
  buildTimeline: ->
    width = @ui.chartWrap.width()
    height = @ui.chartWrap.height()
    console.log height
    dataLength = @data.values.length
    x = d3.time.scale()
      .domain(
        [
          new Date "#{@data.values[0].x}-1-1"
          new Date("#{@data.values[dataLength - 1].x}-1-1")
        ]
      ).rangeRound [0, width - (width/dataLength - 1)]

    y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(
        [
          0
          d3.max(@data.values, (d) ->
            d.y
          )
        ]
      ).rangeRound [height, 0]

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient('bottom')
      .ticks(d3.time.years, 1)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%Y'))

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient('left')
      .tickPadding(8)

    svg = d3.select(@ui.chartWrap[0]).append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)

    # Bars
    svg.append('g')
      .attr('id', 'timeline-bars')
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(@data.values)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", (d) ->
        x(new Date "#{d.x}-1-1")
      )
      .attr("width", width/dataLength - 1)
      .attr("y", (d) ->
        y(d.y)
      )
      .attr("height", (d) =>
        height - y(d.y)
      ).attr("data-date", (d) =>
        d.x
      ).attr("data-count", (d) =>
        d.y
      )

    svg.append("g")
      .attr('id', 'timeline-x-labels')
      .call(xAxis)
```

CSS(SASS) for the chart:

```
  #timeline
    height: 270px
    margin: 10px
    cursor: crosshair
    font-size: 1em

    .bar
      fill: blue
      shape-rendering: crispEdges
      &:hover
        cursor: pointer
        fill: darken(blue, 10)

    #timeline-x-labels
      +translate(0, 240px)
      path, line
        fill: none
        stroke: shade(gainsboro, 10%)
        shape-rendering: crispEdges

      .tick > text
        font-size: 0.7em
        +user-select(none)
        +transform(translate(0px, 10px) rotate(-60deg))
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for us? I would really help.

Comment: I didnt fully understand your code, but my sense is that you need additional variable called lets say padding and when you calculate vertical dimensions of the bars you then use (height - padding) instead of padding. And then use the same padding for positioning x axis.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adjusting the 'x' and 'y' attributes of your graph, try changing the ranges on your scales. If you draw a scale with `.range(50, width)` (or `.rangeround(50, width)`) instead of `(0,width)`, you will effectively give yourself a 50px margin.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting the whole code based on the tutorial here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

Final product looks like this:

```
  buildTimeline: ->
    margin = 
      top: 10
      bottom: 30
      left: 40
      right: 10
    width = @ui.chartWrap.width() - margin.left - margin.right
    height = @ui.chartWrap.height() - margin.top - margin.bottom
    dataLength = @data.values.length

    y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0])

    x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1)

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient 'bottom'

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient('left')
      .tickFormat (d) ->
        prefix = d3.formatPrefix d
        prefix.scale(d) + prefix.symbol

    @chart = d3.select(@ui.chartWrap[0]).append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g').attr('transform', "translate(#{margin.left}, #{margin.top})")

    x.domain _.pluck(@data.values, 'x')
    y.domain [0, d3.max(_.pluck(@data.values, 'y'))]

    @chart.append('g')
      .attr('id', 'timeline-x-axis')
      .attr('class', 'axis')
      .attr('transform', "translate(0, #{height})")
      .call xAxis

    @chart.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis')
      .call yAxis

    @chart.selectAll('.bar')
      .data(@data.values)
      .enter().append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', (d) ->
        x(d.x)
      )
      .attr('y', (d) ->
        y(d.y)
      )
      .attr('height', (d) ->
        height - y(d.y)
      )
      .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
```